# Push Notification Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am Developing an IOS application using sencha touch 2, i have a requirement of sending push notification . I have set apple certificate file, provisional profile also did some server side coding to achieve this. But not sure about is there any push notification service in sencha ? How can i achieve this... Should i use PhoneGap? 
Please direct me in right direction.. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for guiding me in right direction. I used sencha native Device function to send push notification. It will not work in android. I achieved like the following way. I put this code in my app.js file . You will get the device token there. Sent the device token to your server . There you can configure push notification using this device token

```
Ext.device.Push.register({
            type: Ext.device.Push.ALERT|Ext.device.Push.BADGE|Ext.device.Push.SOUND,
            success: function(token) {
                console.log('# Push notification registration successful:');
                console.log('token: ' + token);
                WinReo.app.devicetokenid = token;
                WinReo.app.platform = Ext.device.Device.platform;
                //Ext.Msg.alert('Title', WinReo.app.platform +'', Ext.emptyFn);
            },
            failure: function(error) {
                console.log('# Push notification registration unsuccessful:');
                console.log('     error: ' + error);
            },
            received: function(notifications) {
                console.log('# Push notification received:');
                console.log('    ' + JSON.stringify(notifications));
            }
        });
```

When u first open the app, i will ask whether this app allow push notification message. There you can select yes/no. Later you can edit this setting by go to settings/notification in device.

Answer (score 1):

YES, to make your iOS Sencha-Touch based application support notification, you should use a third party plugin such as mentioned in the documentation :
-Sencha Packager
-PhoneGap
-Simulator

i used the PhoneGap implementation and in the app.js file i put the notifications related infos. when a notification is generated in the backend i send it to the right user based on the session's token stored on the moment of authentification:

```
Ext.Application({
...
//notifications Configuration
notifications : {
    storeTokenUrl   : 'https://adress/whereto/store/token/',
    gcmsenderid     : '0123456789012',
    appid       : 'apple_app_id',
    title       : 'notification title'
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i have to send device token when ever someone installed my app. then i have to send that token id to my server. How can take device token id using phonegap ? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use "Device" object in PhoneGap to get the device's hardware and software properties.
to get the uuid here where to start with exemple: [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid)

Answer (score 0):

When i need to do Push Notification i was using sencha touch 2.0 (latest that time)

I used third party plugins like [urbanairship](http://urbanairship.com/), [pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) and it's good.

For these plugin you need to use PhoneGap.

Refer this links

[cordova-push-notification](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-push-notification)

[Building a Notification App for iOS with Sencha Touch and PhoneGap](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/building-a-notification-app-for-ios-with-sencha-touch-and-phonegap-part-1-of-3/)

[Apple Push Notification Services in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but both  urbanairship, pushwoosh are not free..I can find Ext.device.Push command in sencha touch.. Is it working ? 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Push
Not sure how to user it.. is der any way to do it without Phonegap ?

Comment: ya, you can use Ext.device.Push and it's only supports IOS, I am not sure that Ext.device.Push functions like apple's native push notification, also i didn't use that yet. That's why i didn't mention Ext.device.Push in my answer.. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750876/sencha-touch-2-apple-push-notifications-ext-device-push) question

Comment: Do u have any idea about where to put this push register code. I have just added it in app.js file got an error msg 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Push' of undefined 
Can i test it with browser?
Ext.device.Push.register({

});