# Use Push Notifications for an Android app developed using sencha touch

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, sencha-touch

I would like to know how to implement `push` notifications in an android app developed in `sencha` touch. 
Does `sencha` support android/ios `push` notifications?

Comment: you should use `cordova` and develop the GCM push notification part in native code , and use Plugin to communicate between your sencha code and the native code.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441740/push-notification-sencha-touch-2/18442529#18442529)  question

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. so sencha support android/ios (both of them) push notifications using cordova and develop the GCM push notification part in native code

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch is a client-side library, so you need some native packaging (via Cordova or Sencha's own) in order to connect to Push services.

Sencha's native packager does support Push*:

- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Push

*Sencha Touch 2.3 (when it is released) should support both Push via Sencha's packager as well as Cordova.

But you can also utilize the Sencha Touch Extensions for Windows Azure to use Push as well:

- https://market.sencha.com/extensions/sencha-touch-extensions-for-windows-azure